# How to save data into Firebase child node

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

The user can rate for many places in the application.

This is my current rating:

realtime database:
[image]

When the user try to rate for a new place, the previous rate history will be replaced with the new one. How can I solve this (I want all the rate history to be saved)?

The sample result should be:

```
Rating
   abcde
      rating
         Kamdar sdn bhd
            placename:
            rating:
         theme park
            placename:
            rating:
```

my coding:

```
private void storeUserName(){
        String username;

        FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("Rating");
        UserClass addNewUser = new UserClass(username);
        reference.child(username).setValue(addNewUser);
    }

private void storeUserRating(){
        String username;
        String place_name;
        double rating;

        FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("Rating/"+username);
        RatingClass addNewRating = new RatingClass(place_name,rating);
        reference.child("rating").child(place_name).setValue(addNewRating);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is replaced because you are saving it to the same location. Generate a unique id, to prevent overiding previous data.

```
String id = reference.push().getKey();
```

Then use this id, as a child in your database path

```
reference.child("rating").child(place_name).child(id).setValue(addNewRating);
```

This way data is not replaced.